# Server cant load my web clearly. Need advices

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, base-url

everything works fine until i upload my files into server and server have problems with my base_url.

Try a lot of things, but nothing helps.

now code it is:

```
$config['base_url']    = '';
```

also was:

```
$config['base_url']    = ‘http://’.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) and mores
```

server name is: http://rude.su.lt/~grinius/svetaine/

rude.su.lt - hostname
grinius- my username
svetaine-my web folder

database.php has code:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'rude.su.lt';
$db['default']['username'] = 'grinius';
$db['default']['password'] = '***********';
$db['default']['database'] = 'grinius_database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

view of my web now is: http://postimg.org/image/aj03o96jb/

also then I click on some text i have 404 Not found Error

My code of left column:

```
<? 
 if (!$_SESSION || !$_SESSION['username']) { 
$this->load->helper('form');
echo form_open(base_url() . 'login');
?>
<strong>Iveskite savo duomenis</strong>
<br /><br />
Vartotojas:<br />
<?
echo form_input('username');
?>
<br />Slaptazodis:<br />
<?
echo form_password('password');
?>
<br /><br />
<?
echo form_submit('submit', ' Log in ');
echo form_close();
?>
<br />
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>register">Nauja Registracija</a>
<?
} else {
?>
Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['username'];?>
<br /><br />
<br />
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile">Profilis</a>
<br />
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>logout">Atsijungti</a>
<?
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server config does not support using `<? ... ?>`. Either change the relevant config on server or use `<?php ... ?>` and it will be fine.

Edit:
Try setting `short_open_tag=On` in your php.ini.

Comment: So, how to change this line? "{ 
$this->load->helper('form');
echo form_open(base_url() . 'login');"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code itself. It is the php tag that is causing the issue. So you need to replace every instance of `<?` with `<?php` in the code.

Comment: change, but something wrong with config, or .htacess